# Get Value From index.jsx to Datafeed.js in Trading View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

I have a button in index.jsx which generate

**This button is in `index.js`:**

```js
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (adjustedMode === 'Unadjusted') {          
    setAdjustedMode('adjusted');        
  } else {
    setAdjustedMode('unadjusted')
  }

  button.innerHTML = adjustedMode == 'Unadjusted'
    ? 'Adjusted'
    : 'Unadjusted';        
});
```

**But now I want value adjusted in `DataFeed.js` so I can change the URL to fetch the data.**

getBars: async (
symbolInfo,
resolution,
periodParams,
onHistoryCallback,
onErrorCallback
) => {

```
const { from, to, firstDataRequest } = periodParams;
const defaultTimetamp = 1371100000
// console.log('[getBars]: Method call', symbolInfo, resolution, from, to);
const parsedSymbol = parseFullSymbol(symbolInfo.full_name);
// console.log(symbolInfo)
if (firstDataRequest) {
  try {
    const type = getType(symbolInfo.full_name);
    let data;
    if(symbolInfo.type === "Sector") data = await makeSaralApiRequest(`/sector/chart_data/${type}/1374192000`);
    else{
      if(!isNaN(symbolInfo.send_type)){
      data = await makeSaralApiRequest(
        `/company/chart_data/${symbolInfo.send_type}/${defaultTimetamp}`);
      }
        else{
          data = await makeSaralApiRequest(
            `/company/chart_data_adjusted/${symbolInfo.send_type}`);
        }
    }
    if (data.status != 200 || data.data.length === 0) {
      // "noData" should be set if there is no data in the requested period
      onHistoryCallback([], { noData: true });
      return;
    }
    let bars = [];
    let nepseData = data.data;
    let nepseREv = nepseData;
    nepseREv.forEach((bar) => {
      bars = [
        ...bars,
        {
          time:
            symbolInfo.type === "Sector"
              ? bar.t * 1000 + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
              : bar.t * 1000 + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
          low: bar.l,
          high: bar.h,
          open: bar.o,
          close: bar.c,
          volume: bar.v,
        },
      ];
    });
    // console.log(`[getBars]: returned ${bars.length} bar(s)`);

    // if (bars.length < 1) {
    //     onHistoryCallback([], { noData: true });
    // } else {
    onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
    // }
    // onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
  } catch (error) {
    // console.log('[getBars]: Get error', error);
    onErrorCallback(error);
  }
} else {
  // Return empty result for subsequent requests as TradingView will cache and reuse the data
  onHistoryCallback([], { noData: true });
}
```

},
I need the value in getBars

Now I want it in getBars: which is in **DataFeed.js**

I read documentation and discussion forum but couldn't get the answer required.